# Why cant I do [1] :: [1] but [1] :: [1] :: []

Tags: ocaml

Why can't I use `[1] :: [1]` but `[1] :: [1] :: []`?

I tried to do `[1] :: [1]`. Got this error:

```
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type int list
```

When I do `[1] :: [1] :: []` I get this: `- : int list list = [[1]; [1]]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `[]` is the empty list
- `x :: []` is the same as `[x]`
- `x :: [y]` is the same as  `x :: y :: []` and as `[x; y]`

With your particular examples:

- `[1] :: []` is the same as `[[1]]`
- `[1] :: [1] :: []` is the same as `[[1]; [1]]`
- `[1] :: [1]` would be the same as `[1] :: 1 :: []` and `[[1]; 1]`, but you can't have a list containing mixed types.

Answer (score 2):

@Stef's answer is good. Here is another similar answer.

First, `::` is a *right* associative operator with two operands. The left operand can have any type and the right operand must be a list of that type. The result of the operator is a list with the same type as the right operand.

Second `[]` is an empty list that can have any element type.

Written out fully, lists look like this: `a :: b :: c :: ... :: []`. But they can be written more conveniently as `[a ; b ; c ; ... ]`. The empty list (as mentioned) is `[]`. A list of one element looks like this: `[x]`.

Finally, the elements of a list must all be the same type.

So here is your first case:

```
[1] :: [1] :: []
```

This is a valid list because the elements are all the same type (necessarily since they're the same) and the `::` operators are used correctly with a type on the left and a list of that type on the right. Note that this is only the case because `::` is right associative. So the rightmost `::` is applied first. You could also write this list as `[ [1] ; [1] ]`.

Here is your second case:

```
[1] :: [1]
```

The operator `::` here is not applied correctly. The requirement is that the type of the value on the right be a *list* of the type of the value on the left. Another way to say this is that `int list` is not a list whose elements are type `int list`. To make this valid you can change the left value to be `1` (then you have `int` and `int list` as operands of `::`) or the right value to be `[[1]]` (then you have `int list` and `int list list` as operands of `::`).